Zebra Browser Print in Webapp (React js) in mobile via bluetooth
So I'm working on a Zebra ZD421 to be integrated to my web app, everything is working fine in localhost and deployed server but only in my PC and the printer is connected via USB.
The problem comes when i access my web app on my android phone and connect my zebra via Bluetooth it does not work, it give me an error of

http://localhost:9100/write 500 (Internal Server Error)


http://localhost:9100/read500 (Internal Server Error)".

const handlePrint = async (scanData) => {
    const browserPrint = new ZebraBrowserPrintWrapper();
    const defaultPrinter = await browserPrint.getDefaultPrinter();
    browserPrint.setPrinter(defaultPrinter);
    const printerStatus = await browserPrint.checkPrinterStatus();

    if (printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {
        const zplScript = 
            `^XA
            ^FO320,700^BQN,2,20^FDQA,$14^FS
            ^FO130,950^A0,55,65^FB600,1,0,C^FD$HEllO^FS
            ^XZ`;
        browserPrint.print(zplScript); // Uncomment this to enable actual printing 
    } else {
    console.log("Error/s", printerStatus.errors);
    }
};

To test things I tested in https://cagdemo.com/ and it works fine via Bluetooth. I'm also using ZebraBrowserPrintWrapper. I want to be able to print using my android device
